Have any in vitro generation of tenocytes from pluripotent stem cells been shown to be successful when implemented in a human or in some other animal?
I wonder whether any in vitro generation of tenocytes from pluripotent stem cells been shown to be successful when implemented in a human or at least some other animal. Success = regaining normal function after a tendon injury.
I found some studies explaining how to
perform in vitro generation of tenocytes from pluripotent stem cells
such as https://doi.org/10.1002/jor.25459 but I haven't seen studies on the the actual success of the use once implanted in a human or an animal.
